# How to draw a cubic surface in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

How to draw a [cubic surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface) with tikz?

Comment: A cubic surface is not a simple cube!

Comment: pgfplots can do both z as a function of x and y as well a parametric plots where x,y and z are functions of t.